# Does Zurb Foundation return accurate rems using rem_calc()? Output seems off

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Does Zurb Foundation 5.2.3 return accurate rems using rem_calc()?

Using a base of *12px*, Foundation's rem calculating function *rem_calc()* says that a font size of 148px should equal *9.25rem* ... `rem_calc(148) = 9.25rem;`. The output is visually smaller than what Photoshop says should be *148px*.

Pluging in the base font size and size to be calculated in [Rem Calculator](https://offroadcode.com/prototypes/rem-calculator/) outputs `148px = 12.33rem`. Manually defining a font size of *12.33rem* matches Photoshop.

Where does the difference come from in Foundation? Am I using this function wrong?

**Edit:**
I am not using the wrong REM base, or if I am it's becuase foundation is not looking for it properly. As defined in very top of *Foundation Settings.scss*, before `@import "foundation/functions";` is called...

```
 $base-font-size: 12px;
 $rem-base: $base-font-size;
```

Comment: Try changing `$rem-base: 16px !default;`  in the `_functions.scss`

Comment: Unfortunately that changed nothing. Thanks for getting back though.

Comment: Strange. I'm using Foundation 5 (v 1.0.4) with the SASS 3.3.8 and compass 1.0.0.alpha.19 and it works perfectly fine when i modify     `$rem-base` in the `_settings.scss` i think you are changing it somewhere down the line. Try outputting it with `@debug` command in the different files and find out when it become wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that in Foundation 5.2.3 $rem-base must have a defined font pixel size, simply declaring `$rem-base: $base-font-size;` is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong base:

```
// $rem-base: 16px; // default base
@debug rem-calc(148); //2.25rem

$rem-base: 12px;
@debug rem-calc(148); //12.33333rem

@debug rem-calc(148, 16);// again 2.25rem with the 16 base
```

Comment: Provide some explanation to your answer.